# how to filter google places only specific city regions?

Tags: android, google-maps, filter, autocompletetextview

Unable to filter specific city restrict. Please, anyone give suggestions as wrote below code

```
private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_HYDERABAD = new LatLngBounds(
        new LatLng(17.3850,78.4867), new LatLng(17.3850,78.4867));
Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                                .setFilter(autocompleteFilter)
                                .setBoundsBias(BOUNDS_HYDERABAD)
                                .build(MapsActivity.this);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restrict the data received from Places API. When you set a LatLngBound params, it'll only prioritize the locations from the given LatLngBound, if the given query is not found, it'll then show places from locations outside the given bound.